# Custom Exception - python3

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to create a custom exception by using classes that will handle user input that is NOT in the appropriate range of values I want them to enter (such as a percentage mark must be between 0 and 100), However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code. Thanks

```
mark = 0

class illegal(Exception):
    pass

while True:
   try:
       Mark = int(input("Enter a mark out of 100 to see if its valid or not: "))
       if Mark < 0 or 100 < Mark:
           raise illegal
           break
      except illegal:
         print("Invalid mark")

print("Valid mark")
```

Comment: For starters, your `except` line is indented incorrectly. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes, but refer to my inline comments:

```
class IllegalMark(Exception): # use CamelCase and name meaningfully
    pass

while True:
    try:
        mark = int(input("Enter a mark between 0-100 to test validity: "))
        if mark not in range(0, 101):
            raise IllegalMark
            # break # don't need this since you call 'raise'
    except IllegalMark:
        print("Invalid mark")
        break # if you want to end on invalid, otherwise leave out
```

Comment: Then this is not reproducible and something is wrong on your end; my solution works as it should on Windows and Linux with Python 3.6.4.